# How to break out of async.js map's iterator loop when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

Here `date` is an array. When `if` condition satisfies it has to `break` out of the iterator. But because of iterator it continues looping. Once again it executes `if` condition and throws the error "can't set header after they are sent". I have to break out of iterator once it executes `if` condition.

```
validatemultiday: function(req, callback) {
  async.map(edate, function iterator(date, mapCb) {
    var rangedate = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    if (rangedate == studentfromdate || rangedate == studenttodate) {
      sails.log.info("does1");
      callback(null, 1);
    } else {
      sails.log.info("do2");
      mapCb(null, 2);
    }
  }, callback);
}
```

Comment: what is `async.map`?

Comment: to map the array of data(edate-->date)

Comment: if you would use something, like [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), you could break the iteration with return `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns only false if `if-condition` is executed. It is working.

```
validatemultiday: function(req,callback){
                            var range = true;
                            async.map(edate, function iterator (date, mapCb){
                            var rangedate = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                            if(rangedate==studentfromdate||rangedate==studenttodate){
                                sails.log.info("does2");
                                range=false;
                                mapCb(null,range);
                            }
                            else{
                                sails.log.info("did2");
                                if(range==false){
                                    mapCb(null,range);
                                }
                                else{
                                    range=true;
                                    sails.log.info('2:'+range);
                                    mapCb(null,range);
                                }
                            }
                            });
                            setTimeout(function(){
                            callback(null,range);
                            },100);
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `callback()` or use the `break` statement.

Comment: I had already used callback, but it keep on iterating and once again it executes if condition it returns the error..,

Comment: pass callback to   async.map(edate, function iterator (date, mapCb){

Comment: In if-condition if I change callback-->mapCb it returns output as [1,2,1].I want to return the output [1]  once it executes if-condition

Answer (score 0):

try `break;` or `return;` when you want the loop to stop.

Answer (score 0):

[`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) or [`async.some`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#some) will be useful here.

Use this if you want to do some **async** operation with each date in edate

```
validatemultiday: function(req, callback) {
    async.some(edate, function iterator(date, someCb) {
        var rangedate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var isOnRange = (rangedate == studentfromdate || rangedate == studenttodate);
        // sample async operation: fs.exists
        return fs.exist(rangedate, someCb);
    }, function(result) {
        sails.log.info('validatemultiday', 'result', result);
        return callback(null, result ? 1 : 2);
    });
}
```

---

Use this if there is only **sync** check with each date in edate

```
validatemultiday: function(req, callback) {
    var result = _.some(edate, function(date) {
        var rangedate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var isOnRange = (rangedate == studentfromdate || rangedate == studenttodate);
        return isOnRange;
    });

    return callback(null, result ? 1 : 2);
    // Zalgo alert: Ideally below return statement should be used in place of above one because above code is synchronous to contain Zalgo.
    // return async.nextTick(function() {
    //     return callback(null, result ? 1 : 2);
    // });
}
```

[Zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony): Skip Zalgo stuff, if you are just starting with asynchronous programming.